# Compose error - "Unresolved reference: align" after importing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I was trying to study android jetpack compose and I have found some errors in my code.

`Modifier` has `.align` attributes but it doesn't work.

Other modifiers like padding, clip, etc are working right.

I use

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64

Kotlin 1.6.0
```

My full code:

```
package com.joung.week2_layout

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalProvider
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.joung.week2_layout.ui.theme.Week2LayoutTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            Week2LayoutTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    NameTag()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NameTag() {
    Row{
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .padding(all = 4.dp),
            shape = CircleShape,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface.copy(alpha = 0.2f)
        ) {
            // image url
        }
    }
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(all = 8.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            ){
        Text(text = "Joung", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Text(text = "PHONE NUMBER", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun CardPreview() {
    Week2LayoutTheme {
        NameTag()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an update to this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410877/modifer-align-not-working-for-text-in-row-column-box-unresolved-scope-in/77411562#77411562

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not all modifiers can be used with any composable. They are specific to the type or "scope" of the composable. The `align` modifier cannot be used with the Column composable. To align your content in a Column, use the `verticalArrangement` or `horizontalAlignment` parameters. To center vertically, use `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center`. Also, you are not setting the size of the Column. You should set this. In this example, I set it to `fillMaxSize`. And finally, on a side note, you should be using only the official version of Kotlin. Currently it is 1.5.31 and not 1.6. Using a newer version can cause major issues if Google hasn't been using it yet:

```
Column (
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(all = 8.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
            ){

            }
        }
```

Comment: There is an update to this now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77411562/13572996

Answer (score 2):

`align()` is defined inside `RowScope` or `ColumnScope` which essentially means you must have a parent `Row` or `Column` containing the composable where `align` is being used so that it can align w.r.t the parent. Moreover for `Column` align will be in the horizontal direction and vice versa.

I am not sure about the difference with `align()` but there is a `horizontalAlignment` (for Columns) and `horizontalArrangement` (for Rows) attribute as well for your help. For example:

```
Column {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(all = 8.dp).clip(RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)).align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(text = "Joung", fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Text(text = "PHONE NUMBER", style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2)
        }
    }
}
```