# Modifer.align() not working for text in Row / Column / Box . Unresolved Scope Instance errors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Using Android Studio Giraffe  2022.3.1
So using the preset recommended compiler with this version of android studio

Finding Contradicting online information on `.align()` being able to be used in Column/Row Scope. Some say it doesn't work or only works inside BoxScope.

Yet the android developer introduction [CODELAB](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-text-composables?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-text-composables#9) uses this code and recommends this usage of `Modifier.align()` in columnScope which throws the same errors:

***ERRORS***

Cannot access 'ColumnScopeInstance': it is internal in 'androidx.compose.foundation.layout'

Unresolved reference: End

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScopeInstance.align // import causing the first error
```

```
{                            //Column Scope
            Text(
                text = message,
                fontSize = 100.sp,
                lineHeight = 116.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
            Text(
                text = from,
                fontSize = 36.sp,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .offset(90.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.End), // Error on this line
                textAlign = TextAlign.Left
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align()` can be used for Row,Box and Column. It is a misconception that `align()` only works for box type.

***GENERAL SOLUTION***

***I***.

`.align()` is available under the same name under 3 types

1)Alignment.Horizontal ----> Use inside Column Scope

2)Alignment.Vertical ----> Use inside Row Scope

3)Alignment(There is no extra description) ----> Use inside Box Scope

***II.***

Use the proper Alignment `androidx.compose.ui.Alignment` argument inside `align()` make sure you are using this:

`align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment)`

***III.*** ( Not needed to follow this if there is no import error)

If you have already tried importing you would this in your import statements :

`import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.(Column/Row/Box)ScopeInstance.align`

REMOVE it.

***PROBLEM***

The Issue is the 'overloading' of the Code Completion inteli-sense.

The same key word `"Alignment"` would sometimes be used for `Layout.Alignment` and other times it would be used `androidx.compose.ui.Alignment`.

Inteli-sense is good at understanding this and matches this to the correct type. Yet sometimes it does not work very well so we get the errors.
Similarly the `align()` function has a vertical,horizontal and normal context and inteli-sense can also mismatch the scope with the context.

***My Specific SOLUTION***

`.align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.End)` 
Solved the issue in a column scope. Also I used align in a horizontal context.

[image: ColumnScope Align]

***Make sure this is the Alignment used !***

[image: Align(androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.End)]

***Different types of Alignments***
[image: Alignment]

In my IDE Alignment keyword was taken up by the Layout.Alignment

So don't blindly follow inteli-sense, also just starting to learn android development doesn't help ;).

***P.S : The Myth that `align()` somehow only works in box can be traced to this.***

Answer (score 1):

Just remove your import line. If you really are in a ColumnScope, it will work as you want.
To be sure you are in a ColumnScope, you can check if your composable function/lambda is an extension of ColumnScope :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.ComposableMethod() {
    ...
}
```

or

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ComposableMethodWithLambda(
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit
) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alignment can only be used within Box() component.

just like this:

```
   Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){ 
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 100.sp,
            lineHeight = 116.sp,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .offset(90.dp)
                .align(Alignment.End), // Error on this line
            textAlign = TextAlign.Left
        )
   }
```

and also you can check it out this link:

[Android Jetpack Compose Trying to Align a Text inside a Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70608914/android-jetpack-compose-trying-to-align-a-text-inside-a-box)

Comment: Yeah this code still does not work as Alignment.End throws a type mismatch error when put in a box scope. End is Alignment.Horizontal it wants only Alignment, So something like Alignment.Center works.

Comment: I edited my code. I added filmaxsize to Box scope. Maybe it's not happening because it doesn't cover an area. I can't say anything since I can't see the full code right now, but can you try it this way?